# Partial panorama (iPhone panorama), three.js or Pannellum?

Tags: javascript, three.js, partial, panoramas, pannellum

For 2 weeks now, I have been struggling with this issue, not using Pannellum, but with all kinds of Js libraries, among them ThreeJS, with no success. Pannellum looks promissing, and have seen that it supports partial panoramas (1 photo).
Basically I want to build a panorama player like the one on Facebook. I have uploaded panorama photos taken with my iPhone, and they are not 360 degr.
In short, can anyone provide me with an example of partial panorama using Pannellum or Three.js? Then I would be very happy and thankful.

Answer (score 1):

If someone need it.

```
  pannellum.viewer('panorama3', {
    "type": "equirectangular",
    "panorama": "Link",
    "autoLoad": true,
    "haov": 180,
    "vaov": 62,
    "minYaw": -76.935,
    "maxYaw": 76.935,
    "minPitch": -27.905,
    "maxPitch": 30.245,
    "showZoomCtrl": false,
    "mouseZoom": false,
    "keyboardZoom": false,
    "hfov": 80,
    "orientationOnByDefault": true
});
```